# Git not working. Installed XCode

Tags: xcode, git, macos

Using an iMac running OSX 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion). It's a work computer and can't upgrade to a higher OS version at the moment for various reasons.

I tried installing XCode so that I can use Git but it isn't working.

In terminal I run:
git --version

and get this response:
-bash: git: command not found

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Almost 8years later after your post, I have installed xcode to macOS Monterey, I have been using git daily before installation, now it is gone, really sad that xcode installation is so invasive :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install git separately:
http://burnedpixel.com/blog/setting-up-git-and-github-on-your-mac/

Comment: Thank you for the link. This is what I needed to do first. 

(from the guide you posted)
--------
We need to make sure the Terminal goes through the correct order of folders to discover your newer version of Git.
$ echo "export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile

# Tell the Terminal to look at your bash_profile to get the updated order of folders (your "$PATH")
$ source ~/.bash_profile

# Now let's check your Git version again
$ git --version

# You should now see the version number corresponding to the DMG you downloaded (e.g. 1.8.1.3)
------

Answer (score 0):

Source control was only introduced into Xcode 4. This however does not mean git is installed onto your system as part of downloading Xcode. It just means that you can use some git features in a Xcode project by pressing the source control button at the top. To install the actual git go [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads).

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't know why it appears to be so, but it looks like Git still isn't installed on your computer. Another way to check if Git is installed is by using the `which git` command. If that still doesn't help, install it separately. [Download Git for Mac](http://git-scm.com/download/mac).